# User account upgrade via PayPal Digital goods. How do I link payer to the user?

Tags: paypal

When some user pays for an upgrade, how do I detect which one when I'm doing aftermath( providing access) ?

After making transaction(on Digital goods) PayPal returns a lot of details. Like:
PROFILEID, STATUS, SUBSCRIBERNAME, PROFILESTARTDATE etc.

But there's no way to find which one of the users should be given an upgrade. Can I pass any variable containing user information to PayPal, using Digital Goods flow ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the GetExpressCheckoutDetails operation to get the CUSTOM parameter for this token. Do this before the DoExpressCheckout operation.

You would set the value of CUSTOM on the initial call to PayPal (on the SetExpressCheckout request).